# Separate template path for a subdomain

Tags: templates, subdomain, routing

I want to set the template path specifically for a subdomain - outside of the default_site templates, while still using the same site/entries/data. MSM isn't what I need here and related posts I can find just uses a template group inside of the current set of templates.

So far I have the subdomain loading the site and hitting my conditional in index.php:

```
if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 'sub.domain.com')
{

    $assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://sub.domain.com/';
    $assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'admin';
    $assign_to_config['template_group'] = 'home';

    $assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array(
    'subsite_id' => 'admin_site',
    'domain' => 'http://sub.domain.com/',
    'site_name' => 'Admin Portal',
    ); 
}
```

My main default_site template path resolves as `/home/site/public_html/templates/default_site`
I want the subdomain path to use `/home/site/public_html/templates/admin_site`

Is there a param I can add to set the template path when coming in on the subdomain? Are any edits needed to .htaccess as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're looking for [tmpl_file_basepath](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#tmpl-file-basepath)

```
$config['tmpl_file_basepath'] = '/home/site/public_html/templates/admin_site';
```

You could also consider using [FocusLab Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config), which makes a multi-environment approach much cleaner.

Comment: Actually that looks like that is only available in the config.php file via $config['tmpl_file_basepath'], not in the index. Testing it in config with the same condition doesn't affect the path either, still loading the default_site templates.  Thank you for the master config though, I will look into that now.